# Возможно ли при входящем звонке вывести дополнительную инфу о номере?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Возможно ли при входящем звонке вывести дополнительную инфу о звонящем на ваш телефон номере? Т.е. может ли приложение, с учетом последних изменений 8.1, получить доступ к звонящему вам номеру во время звонка и вывести в эту область дополнительную информацию?

Платформа: Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1):

В центре разработчиков мелкомягких ответили, что такое сделать невозможно, доступа к этому API нету.